# Pandas groupby() + apply() to create csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I'm using pandas groupby()+apply() to run a function from another script and create a csv from the output. It seems to work until the end when writing the dataframe to a csv, where it returns a csv with nothing in it.

I import the function written in the other script and read the input csv:

```
from FILE import FUNCTION

df= pd.read_csv('/path/input.csv')
```

Then create an empty dataframe, use groupby() + apply() to apply the function to the groups, then write the new csv:

```
df2 = []
df2 = df.groupby("column.1").apply(FUNCTION)
# #
# #
# #
df2.to_csv('/path/new.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

I can't figure out why it's returning an empty csv as it seems everything is working until the very end of the script.

Comment: Try `print(df2)` to check if it contains the desired data.

Comment: There is no point in `df2 = []` (an empty LIST) since in the next line you re-assign the name to another object,

Comment: What is your function doing? As the previous person suggested - print the results so we can see what is showing before converting to a csv.

Answer (score 0):

Depends highly on the function your applying. Does it return a dataframe or a series?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Groupby result in a series if there is only one column.(assuming there is content), so using the pandas dataframe will not work anymore

Try to do the following before you write the csv

`df2 = df2.reset_index()`

And then write the csv

The reset_index() rebuilds a pandas datafrane from the series